# Simple wordpress is_single get the category id

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

We want to be able to display scrollers on post pages.
The code below was indented for category pages; it removes scroller base taxonomy and replaces it with category taxonomy.

We tried replacing the is_category with is_single, and it doesn't work for post pages.

```
function metaslider_restrict_to_current_category( $args, $slide, $slider_settings, $slide_settings ) {

    // check slide ID so we only apply this functionality where it's needed

    // replace "123" with the slide ID to target.

    if ( $slide->ID == 123 && is_category() ) {

        // remove any existing restrictions
        if ( isset ( $args['tax_query'] ) ) {
            unset( $args['tax_query'] );
        }

        // restrict to posts tagged to the current category
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => get_query_var( 'cat' )
            );

    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'metaslider_post_feed_args', 'metaslider_restrict_to_current_category', 10, 4);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the context here? It's not clear what you are trying to do or what is actually failing.

Comment: Hi Ben , the code is intended for Category pages , we're trying to hack the code to work on post pages

Comment: It's does't work on post pages , it's does not strip out the global categories and only show the current post categories